# Editing an SMS text in an active journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I am trying to edit / update an SMS text in a journey but pausing it doesn't give me the function to edit it. If I stop the journey, I have to restart it and then everyone in the journey has to get the emails in that same journey again. Anyone know how to edit an SMS text in an already active journey without stopping it and having to have the journey re start?

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet possible, there is no option to edit an sms in a live journey.

The only possibility is to create a new version of the journey, update the sms copy there and activate it.

Comment: I figured it out. It was possible by editing it in the content builder. It automatically updated the live journey!

Answer (score 0):

@Sara Strome

If you test the journey you will notice that the SMS has been changed but what is in the journey remains old